# Accessing a List element from another List -- MATLAB

Tags: arrays, list, matlab, indexing

I  have a question. I have an list

```
L1 - {'a','b','c'} 
L2 - {'d','e','f'}
```

I am storing the L1 and L2 in a separate list, so that I can loop through it i.e

```
X - {'L1','L2'}
```

Now, I am not able to do this operation X{1}{1}. Does any one know an alternative?

I need to access the element 'a'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the cell array of cells `X`, you need to write

```
X = {L1,L2};
```

Then you can access `X{1}{1}`